# Scan lists with similar names

Tags: list-manipulation

How I can scan a range of lists with similar names?

For example, I have the list names: Treatment1Group3Tested1Repeat4.
and I want to scan only in groups 4 to 7 of treatment 2 certain value in the list.

How can I use a loop that scans the few lists when the difference between the lists is a number in the middle of the name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firsrt you need to extract the numbers from the string,. This can be done with StringCases:

```
getDigits[str_] := ToExpression[StringCases[str, DigitCharacter ..]]
```

ToExpression is needed bacause StringCases returns a string, but we need a number.

With this helper function we can then select the valid file names. E.g. with some arbitrary file names:

```
fnames = {"Treatment1Group3Tested1Repeat4", 
   "Treatment2Group4Tested1Repeat4", "Treatment2Group5Tested1Repeat2",
    "Treatment2Group5Tested1Repeat333"};
validFN=Select[fnames, (4 <= getDigits[#][[2]] <= 7) && (getDigits[#][[1]] == 
     2) &]
```

With the valid file names you can now do whatever you please. However, I would not use a loop, but Map like:

```
Map[your job,validFN ] or (your job)&/@ validFN
```

Comment: validFN give me only the lists names (like Treatment2Group4Tested1Repeat4), how I scan the data inside the lists? And is it possible to go back through validFN to the original list and change value inside? (like an exchange of value according to a rule I wrote)

Comment: Having the valid file names, you need to read them of courseThen you can do whatever you like with the data.